# Set the profile pictures globally

Tags: exchange, outlook, exchange-2013, microsoft-office-365, lync

I'm trying to set my profile picture (avatar) globally, so that it will be available in all services connected to my exchange server.

As described in [Changing a user's on-premises photo](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2973171), I successfully changed my picture in Office 365. Unfortunately it still isn't available on other accounts (e.g. Lync, Outlook) in the same domain.
Then experimentally I changed my pictures in Lync and Outlook, nevertheless, neither of them are visible on other accounts.

Is there a way to globally change pictures (over Office 365), so that they will be available to all services connected over the exchange server?

PS: I'm using Office 365, where the services are connected through Exchange Server 2013.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the best way to do photos is with Active Directory. I'm assuming you are federated with Dirsync running. If so, there's a free tool from Cjwdev called *AD Photo Edit Free* that makes it easy to add pictures to user accounts in AD. Without a tool like that, you have to do crazy PowerShell stuff. You have to make the photos square before you add them, but you don't have to worry about resolution because the tool will do that for you. When you use the tool, you do have to tell it to re-size the photos to 96x96 or you'll get an error.

Once you've added them to on-premise AD using the tool, they will be both Dirsynced up to Office 365 and also accessed by the Outlook client to show up in Outlook for all users. They will also show up in Lync and online in the Office 365 web portal, OWA, Sharepoint Online, etc. I think if you separately upload a photo using the Office 365 web portal, it will override the AD photo but only on the web portal. Outlook on-premise will definitely keep pulling from AD. Note that there is some lag time before people start seeing photos after you've added them to AD, even if you kick off a manual Dirsync right away. It seems that the clients (Outlook, Lync/Skype, etc.) can take some time to re-query for photos.